# Using ng-change to populate one dropdown based on the selection of another in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, A keyword will be selected from the first dropdown and based on that a second dropdown with "Qualifiers" will be populated.I cant get anything to populate in the qualifier dropdown how will I be able to pass the keyword to the service? or am I already doing that with `ng-change="getQualifier(keyword)"` but I may need to modify the service to take in a parameter right?

this is my angular controller that handles these too dropdowns

```
var StockItemMultiMillInquiryController = function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, $modal, $window, StockItemMultiMillService, QualifierService, KeywordService) {


$rootScope.title = 'Stock Item Multi Mill Inquiry';
$scope.allMills = [];
$scope.mill = '';
$scope.stockNumber = '';
$scope.description = '';
$scope.qtyonhand = '';
$scope.qualifier = '';
$scope.costType = '';
$scope.keyword = '';
$scope.allKeywords = [];
$scope.qualifier = '';
$scope.selectedQualifier = '';
$scope.allQualifiers = [];


KeywordService.getKeyword().then(function (keywords) {
    $scope.allKeywords = keywords
});

$scope.getQualifiers(keyword)
{
    QualifierService.getQualifier(keyword).then(function(qualifiers) {
        $scope.allQualifiers = qualifiers
    });
}
```

the services this is using

```
app.service('QualifierService', function ($http, cache) {
return {
    getQualifier: function () {
        var qualifiers = cache.get('qualifier');
        if (!qualifiers) {
            return $http({ method: 'JSONP', url: "/api/core/qualfier/qualifier?callback=JSON_CALLBACK", params: {} }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data.success) {
                    cache.put('qualifier', result.data.data);
                    return result.data.data;
                } else {
                    return [];
                }
            });
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(qualifiers);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
};
});
```

the htm page

```
<select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="keyword" ng-change="getQualifier(keyword)">
    <option value="">Select a Keyword</option>
    <option ng-repeat="keyword in allKeywords" value="{{keyword.description}}"> {{keyword.description}} </option>
</select><br/><br/>

<select  class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="selectedQualifier">
    <option value="">Select a Qualifier</option>
    <option ng-repeat="qualifier in allQualifiers" value="{{qualifier.description}}"> {{qualifier.description}} </option>
</select>
```

.Net Controller that the  service calls

```
  Function Qualifier(callback As String, keyword As String) As ActionResult
    Dim res As New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.Response

    Dim qualifierList As New List(Of ViewModels.Core.Qualifier)
    For Each u As Trident.Core.Core.Qualifier In Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.ApplicationCache.Keywords.Qualifiers(keyword)
        qualifierList.Add(New ViewModels.Core.Qualifier(u))
    Next
    Try
        res.success = True
        res.message = ""
        res.data = qualifierList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.description)
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    Catch ex As Exception
        res.success = False
        res.message = ex.Message
        res.data = ""
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see a `getQualifier` function defined in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put ng-change on your first dropdown as its triggered when the value of the select element is changed, not the data.

Comment: ok done, but nothing happens. i think keyword is not passing to the service or the service is not passing keyword to the .net controller.

Comment: do what i said before, plus this.
add on your controller.
function getQualifiers(keyword) {
QualifierService.getQualifier(keyword).then(function (qualifiers) {
    $scope.allQualifiers = qualifiers
});
}
assume that on your service, your getqualifier method takes in a parameter.

Comment: its because you didnt wrap your service call, in a function. therefore, its only called once when the controller is initialized, but wrapping it in a function allows the ng-change to call it everytime a keyword changes, passing it the keyword.

Comment: i modified the function and edited my post is that what you were saying? i tried it and the list for keyword disappeared. how would i modify the service though to take the parameter the .net controller that is called by the service that goes to the db is called Qualifier. ill post it as well

Comment: you have to add getQualifiers to your scope to use it in the html. $scope.getQualifiers(keyword){} on your controller. and the ng-change goes in the first select element

Comment: i made the change  to it and the html but keyword dropdown data disappears. i updated the code in the post to reflect my current code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple working example:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="moviesCtrl">
      <h1>Movies By My Favorite Directors</h1>
      <select ng-model="director">
        <option ng-repeat="director in directors" value="{{ director.id }}">{{ director.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <select ng-model="film">
        <option ng-repeat="film in movies[director].films" value="{{ film.id }}">{{ film.title }} starring {{ film.lead }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('moviesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.directors = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Stanley Kubrick"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Quentin Tarantino"
    }
  ];
  $scope.movies = [
    {
      directorId: 0,
      films: [
        {
            id: 0,
          title: "The Shining",
          lead: "Jack Nicholson"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
          title: "A Clockwork Orange",
          lead: "Malcolm McDowell"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
          title: "2001: A Space Odyssey",
          lead: "Keir Dullea"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      directorId: 1,
      films: [
        {
            id: 3,
          title: "Pulp Fiction",
          lead: "John Travolta"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
          title: "Inglorious Buddies",
          lead: "Brad Pitt"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
          title: "Django Unchained",
          lead: "Jamie Foxx"
        }
      ]
    },
  ];
});
```

For some reason this would not work in a jsFiddle, but it works in Chrome.